# UITableView cell font size

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to make the text "automatically" smaller if the text in one row is longer than it can fit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep:

```
UILabel *myLabel = /* init the label */
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

For iOS 7 :

```
myLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;  // Float from 0 to 1; as a scale of init size.
```

For iOS 6 and Prior :

```
myLabel.minimumFontSize = 10;  // Float value, in pixels (int value recom'd).
```

You can read more in [Apple's `UILabel` docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth).

Comment: In such case my text resizes as per label. If I want to resize my label as per text then ??

Comment: Should be using `minimumScaleFactor` now, not minimumFontSize.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's been a few years, but I when I found this answer I also discovered an easier way.
This is instead of creating your own label, use the one in the cell.

```
cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
cell.textLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.6;
```

Comment: In my opinion this is the answer to the question that was asked. UITableViewCell.textLabel is a UILabel.